# Python import package - __init__.py is not executed

Tags: python, import, package, python-import, importerror

I know there are several similar topics discussed here, but none of them was helpful for this problem.

I have the following file structure:

lib/
      Linearalgebra/
                              __init__.py
                              vector.py

The lib/ directory is in my PYTHONPATH, I doublechecked it by printing `sys.path`.

The __init__.py file contains the code `from vector import Vector`.
The vector.py file contains a class called Vector

Now if i run the following script

```
import Linearalgebra
v1 = Linearalgebra.Vector([1, 1])
```

I get  `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Vector'`

When I run this code in order to check what actually gets imported

```
import Linearalgebra
print Linearalgebra
```

I get `<module 'Linearalgebra' from '...lib/Linearalgebra.py'>`

I think I should get `<module 'Linearalgebra' from '...lib/Linearalgebra/__init__.py'>`

Why is __init__.py not executed?

Comment: Seems like you have another file in lib called Linearalgebra.py, which is shadowing your Linearalgebra package.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked out. There was a Linearalgebra.py in lib, but it was displayed as Linearalgebra in the mac os x finder. When I looked at the lib directory using the command line tool (bash ls) it showed the .py extension. I removed the extension and everything worked. Thanks again for the super speedy and helpful reply.